# Windows metro style app on windows mobile phone

Tags: windows, windows-8

Can I use windows metro style (hybrid app) development style (C++ plus Java script) to write windows mobile phone app?

Thanks
Raj

Comment: check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681687(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It depends what APIs and UI elements you have used.
If its a library kind of application where you have used basic APIs available in both the platform it may work. But most of the time is not the scenario. As mentioned by user88975's link if you have used XAML UI in Metro app than you have to change it. And many more things.

In short... no, its not possible as of now.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have to start from scratch. I have to build a simple windows phone app talks to the cloud server by making statless http api calls and would also utilize push service. My UI elements involves basic buttons,and text boxes and labels. If so can I try the hybrid model? If you rule out that, what would be next best choice. Also can I use C# instead of C++ ? So I assume except the hybrid model, I have choose XAML for UI. Am i right?

Comment: As you can't have XAML UI on Windows Phone. To start working on WP, using respective text boxes, label, buttons and other components.

Comment: We are now usning XAML and C# fow windows 8 phone